# need help creating html elements with a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, dom

I am trying to create inputs in my html and am using a for loop to generate a random amount every time a button is clicked. I click the button, the console prints out the random number but only one input is generated. It is even printing out the correct number of `console.logs`, just not the inputs. I am not sure why and would love any help.

```
const generateRanNum = () => {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    return randomNumber
}



const generateInputs = (ranNum) => {
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    for(let i = 1; i <= ranNum; i++){
        inputsList.appendChild(listItem);
        listItem.appendChild(input);
        console.log(ranNum)

    }


}

startButton.onclick = () => {
   const ranNum = generateRanNum()
    generateInputs(ranNum)
    // alert('clicked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `const input = document.createElement('input');` should go **inside** the `for` loop.
- don't forget to insert your LI in the respective UL **after** the loop.

```js
const generateInputs = (ranNum) => {
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');

    for(let i = 1; i <= ranNum; i++){
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        listItem.appendChild(input);
    }

    inputsList.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

Comment: You're right and it works just fine now. Why does the ```const input``` need to be inside the loop and not also ```const listItem```, aren't both being generated by the for loop?

Comment: @AndrewLovato read the code carefully... in other words it says: *"**for** a **random** number of times, **create** element input, and **append** it"*. That should answer your question. If it's created outside of the loop, you'll end up appending the same one input over and over again.

Comment: You need one `listItem` or many? If you need one input inside one li, than move all the code inside the `for` loop.

Comment: oh I see, ok, yes that makes sense now.